# Intellisense/peek definition on external large dependencies in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2019

I'm having issues with visual studio's intellisense not working very well with complex types, leaving with little or no visibility of methods/properties.

I have a nuget dependency on a class library that contains a type with many hundred methods (effectively its a schema definition).

Normally this wouldnt be an issue, intellisense would simply bring up the available methods and life would be easy...but Visual Studio isnt cooperating, at best it takes 3 minutes to construct the list of options, thats if its actually doing anything, it would seem reasonable to peek the definition, but similarly this does nothing, and going to the definition brings up "Cannot navigate to symbol under the caret".

So my options seem to be to go and find the source code of the external dependency (which luckily I can do), but this seems at best irritating.....any suggestions?...is there a way to simply browse the class/type/interfaces inside an external dependency?

(sorry for posting this in F#, but I suspect this may be an idiosyncracy of visual studios F# editor).

Comment: You would normally use Visual Studio's "Object Browser" but it doesn't work for F# projects. What about searching for your package on https://fuget.org instead? For example: https://www.fuget.org/packages/Giraffe/4.1.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Giraffe.dll/Giraffe/Auth

Comment: ah I did wonder about good old object browser, havent used it since vb6!....but yes...it didnt work....I'll look at fuget

Comment: ah my packages exist in my own artifact repository on azure...so fuget isnt going to work

Comment: this is why I have access to the source code...but the source code is immense (its auto generated), so having the projects open just makes visual studio choke.

Comment: You could make a C# project (in a dummy solution maybe?) referencing your package and use object browser from there.

Comment: Brilliant...if you put that as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted one. I think thats as good as it gets.

Comment: actually that only half worked, for some reason it wont show me the base types (interfaces) of my interfaces, so it wont show me the members...but almost